# How to handle the login/logout state in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am looking for proper authentication strategy to be used with Next.Js. Currently, I am sending cookie token and `userInfo` object from backend server(nestjs) if token is valid.

I had to use `redis` on server and `localstorage` on client to hold the state because I am unable to access `cookie token` on client (components in nextjs) and the `localstorage` on server (pages in nextjs)

So how do I:

1. Make of `cookie token` sent from server on client to manage the state on nextjs?
2. Redirect the user to login page on nextjs when 403 error is received from server in cases of token expiration? (May be with middleware in nextjs)

Or is there any better alternative to manage the state in nextjs along the usage of already implemented `cookie token` on server

Comment: Have you looked into https://next-auth.js.org/ its a very popular and used library for next authentication. I noticed you included it as a tag but not in the post body